# Cropzoom PNG re-sizing issues

Tags: jquery, png, crop, image-resizing, jcrop

I've recently upgraded to Cropzoom 1.1 and began encountering issues re-sizing png files. I receive the following error.

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'filter' of undefined"

Web inspector is pointing at the following lines of code.

```
var ext = getExtensionSource();
if (ext == 'png' || ext == 'gif')
    $image.style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='"
        + $options.image.source
        + "',sizingMethod='scale');";
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Also had the same challenge. From what I can deduce, it is related to PNG file having transparency. CropZoom wants to apply AlphaImageLoader to it, but in many browsers it isn't a supported action, and not even needed.
My error reported on line 163ish of jquery.cropzoom.js, so I took a peek, and did a quick edit from:

```
 if (ext == 'png' || ext == 'gif')
                $image.style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='"
                    + $options.image.source
                    + "',sizingMethod='scale');";
```

To:

```
if ((ext == 'png' || ext == 'gif')  && $.browser.msie)
                $image.style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='"
                    + $options.image.source
                    + "',sizingMethod='scale');";
```

And it works.

This may need versioning checking too, I think the intent of this code was if the extension supported transparency, use IE's DXImageTransform to make it appear transparent in the cropzoom tool. I think it's primarily needed for older versions of IE.